# Is integration by parts the best method for $\int_0^1 x^3(1-x)^6 dx$?

Tags: probability, self-learning

It came up when finding a constant such that the integral is equal to 1 and thus behaves like a pdf. I used the parts method but have made an error, just curious how others might approach the problem.

Comment: I'd probably either use integration by parts directly or take $u=1-x$ so that I could expand a binomial to the third power instead of the sixth power.

Comment: As a side note this is a Beta Distribution with $cf(x),\alpha=4,\beta=7$ where $c=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}$.

Comment: See [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The beta function is the **best** idea.

$$\beta(a, b) = \int_{0}^{1} x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1} dx$$

For here $I$, let $a = 4, b = 7$

Using:

$$\beta(a, b) = \frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}$$

$$\beta(4, 7) = \frac{\Gamma(4)\Gamma(7)}{\Gamma(11)} = \frac{3!6!}{10!}$$

$$= \frac{3\cdot2\cdot1}{10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7} = \frac{1}{840}$$

Comment: Nice, was just working on this answer after thinking about it :)

Comment: @Chris, thanks =)

Answer (score 11):

This way might be faster, but it ultimately depends on your personal preference.

Let $u = 1-x$.  Then the integral becomes:

$$\int (u-1)^3u^6 \  \text{d}u$$

And that expansion is much easier to work with than the original!

Comment: Be careful with the sign of the definite integral if you do this method though.

Comment: Indeed @GFauxPas.  We picked up a negative since $du = -dx$, which I incorporated into the binomial.

Comment: But also, the transformation will have the bounds be from $1$ to $0$ rather than from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: Oh sure.  I usually do the integral as is, then at the end sub back in whatever $u$ was and evaluate at the original bounds.  Just a weird habit of mine.

Comment: I also tend to sub back and evaluate the original bounds.

Answer (score 4):

By symmetry,

\begin{align}
\int_0^1 x^3(1-x)^6\,\mathrm{d}x &= -\int_1^0x^6(1-x)^3\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-\int_0^1 (x-1)^3x^6\,\mathrm{d}x \\
&=-\int_0^1 x^9-3x^8+3x^7-x^6 \,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-\left(\frac{1}{10}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{3}{8}-\frac{1}{7}\right)+0\\\\
&=-\frac{84-280+315-120}{840}\\
&=\boxed{\displaystyle\frac{1}{840}}
\end{align}

Comment: Check your signs; you're integrating something positive. Also this is the solution I just posted...

Comment: @pre-kidney Thanks. I didn't see yours when I posted mine (look at the differences in time - I don't think anyone can type that fast). Also it's the solution Kaj posted 15 minutes ago :P

Answer (score 2):

Along the lines of Kaj, I think the fastest is to just expand:
$$
\int x^3(1-x)^6 = \int (1-u)^3u^6=\int u^6-3u^7+3u^8-u^9=\frac{1}{7}-\frac{3}{8}+\frac{3}{9}-\frac{1}{10}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

If we realize the integral is part of the Beta Distribution:
$$\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1},0<x<1$$
We find $\alpha=4,\beta=7$. We also know the integral of any pdf equals $1$ and thus this our coefficient must be the inverse of the result.

Answer (score 0):

using that $$x^3(1-x)^6=x^9-6 x^8+15 x^7-20 x^6+15 x^5-6 x^4+x^3$$ we can calculate the integral without the beta function, we get
$$\int_{0}^{1} x^9-6 x^8+15 x^7-20 x^6+15 x^5-6 x^4+x^3dx=\frac{1}{840}$$